# how to remove redundant data from multiple join queries

Tags: sql-server

hello there i wanted to remove redundant data from the multiple join queries. but i'm getting duplicate data after running this query.

INVOICE TABLE

[image: INVOICE]

INVOICE_DETAILS TABLE

[image: INVOICE_DETAILS]

JOB_DETAILS TABLE

[image: JOB_DETAILS]

IMP_BILLING_TERMS_DETAILS TABLE

[image: IMP_BILLING_TERMS_DETAILS]

RESULT AFTER RUN THIS QUERY 
[image: RESULT]

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            INV.bill_ID,
            INV.Bill_No,
            Agency_Charges = (SELECT DISTINCT IBTD.Amount_Paid
            FROM Invoice_Details INV_details inner join Imp_Billing_Terms_Details IBTD on INV_details.Billing_Term_ID_Auto = IBTD.Billing_Terms_ID_Auto AND IBTD.Billing_Term_ID = '1033' 
            WHERE INV_details.Invoice_ID = INV.bill_ID)
FROM Invoice INV inner JOIN Job_Details JD on INV.Job_ID = JD.Job_ID
WHERE JD.Job_No is not null and INV.Bill_No is not null and JD.Gen_Bill = 'Y' AND JD.Company_ID='2'
```

Comment: GIven you are running distinct, then you are not getting duplicates, there will be a difference somewhere in the columns.

Without knowing your source metadata it's impossible to advise on this.,

Comment: Hi updated code please check

Comment: OK:
1) I don't know why you think outer apply is necessary here, you can just use a left join, you are not using a table-value function.
2) Should IBTD. AmountPaid be an aggretation?

For possible missing joins:

3) For INV to JD - can there be more than one JobNo per JobID? If so, you are missing that join.
4) For INV to INV_details - Can there be more than one JobID per bill_id / invoice_id (also why are these different names? This is bad DW design), as it's not in the join.
5) IBTD to INV - Can there be more than one JobID per BIlling_Terms_ID_Auto? because there is no join .

Comment: hi code updated 1) removed outer apply 2) which aggregation should i use here 3) only one job id will be there depend on that job id there will be multiple INV and against that INV there will be multiple Invoice_Details  and Imp_billing_terms_details IBTD (ID in to invoice details) and want compare invoice_Details.billing_term_id_auto = IBTD.billing_Term_ID_auto and IBTD.biliing_term_ID = 1033 4) only one job id will be there per bill id 5) no there will be only one job id per billing_term_Id_auto

Comment: So in your results screenshot you have two rows for `bill_id` 2156, which you claim are duplicates.  These are not duplicates, because it indicates that you are also returning one or more values for `jd.inv_exp` that are not 'I' or that may be `null`.  If you add that column to your select statement you will see this.  If you only want 'I', then you need a `where` statement to that effect.  If you want only one row to return an `Agency_Charge` of either 0 or a value depending on whether it has an `jd.inv_exp` of 'I' or not, then please advise and I will write as an answer.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: i'm getting JD.IMP_EXP = 'I' after return in select statement and i want agency charge if available else want to return 0 if IBTD.Billing_Term_ID = '1033' not found, so please write answer

Comment: hello @TJB thanks for your comment i got the solutions please check query again